# Fail2ban is actually failing to ban, but it says it is banning

Tags: fail2ban

I've run across a few other articles that show the same exact issue. Here's what my logs are showing from fail2ban:

```
2018-09-26 22:16:52,286 fail2ban.filter         [24743]: INFO    [core_404] Found 172.16.38.1 - 2018-09-26 22:16:52
2018-09-26 22:16:52,733 fail2ban.filter         [24743]: INFO    [core_404] Found 172.16.38.1 - 2018-09-26 22:16:52
2018-09-26 22:16:52,927 fail2ban.actions        [24743]: NOTICE  [core_404] 172.16.38.1 already banned
2018-09-26 22:16:53,118 fail2ban.filter         [24743]: INFO    [core_404] Found 172.16.38.1 - 2018-09-26 22:16:53
2018-09-26 22:16:53,431 fail2ban.filter         [24743]: INFO    [core_404] Found 172.16.38.1 - 2018-09-26 22:16:53
2018-09-26 22:16:53,529 fail2ban.actions        [24743]: NOTICE  [core_404] 172.16.38.1 already banned
2018-09-26 22:16:53,605 fail2ban.filter         [24743]: INFO    [core_404] Found 172.16.38.1 - 2018-09-26 22:16:53
2018-09-26 22:16:53,768 fail2ban.filter         [24743]: INFO    [core_404] Found 172.16.38.1 - 2018-09-26 22:16:53
2018-09-26 22:16:53,823 fail2ban.filter         [24743]: INFO    [core_404] Found 172.16.38.1 - 2018-09-26 22:16:53
2018-09-26 22:16:54,131 fail2ban.actions        [24743]: NOTICE  [core_404] 172.16.38.1 already banned
2018-09-26 22:16:54,225 fail2ban.filter         [24743]: INFO    [core_404] Found 172.16.38.1 - 2018-09-26 22:16:54
2018-09-26 22:16:54,381 fail2ban.filter         [24743]: INFO    [core_404] Found 172.16.38.1 - 2018-09-26 22:16:54
2018-09-26 22:16:54,933 fail2ban.actions        [24743]: NOTICE  [core_404] 172.16.38.1 already banned
```

If I look at `iptables -L`, I see this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
f2b-core_404  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https
f2b-core   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain f2b-core (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  172.16.38.1          anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain f2b-core_404 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  172.16.38.1          anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

But yet it's still not banning the IP address. What exactly does `already banned` means if it's actually not already banned? This is so confusing and frustrating.

Here's what my `jail.conf` file looks like:

```
[core]
enabled = true
filter  = core
port    = http,https
logpath = /home/user/Documents/rails/portal/log/devise.log
bantime = 3600
findtime = 600
maxretry = 2

[core_404]
enabled = true
filter  = core_404
port    = http,https
logpath = /home/user/Documents/rails/portal/log/404.log
bantime = 3600
findtime = 600
maxretry = 2
```

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

Here's another situation. Same thing, says already banned. But if I go to iptables, it's empty:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain f2b-core_404 (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**EDIT**

Another thing I just tried -- `ufw` status is 'inactive' and this is my iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  <my_ip>      anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Still not blocking that IP address. It seems like IP blocking on this DigitalOcean VPS is impossible

Comment: Not sure about IP tables itself but do you actually have any actions defined? How do you test if you’re blocked or not?

Comment: I'm using `curl` on the system residing at the source IP address. I completely took fail2ban out of the equation and just simply trying to work from iptables at the moment. Seems impossible to block this source IP address and I'm not sure where the conflict is.

Comment: Check that curl is not connecting via private IP and you are blocking public etc.

Comment: It seems that my issue here is Cloudflare. Apparently you can't use iptables to ban  IPs if you're behind Cloudflare.

Comment: You can use [clouflare](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.11/config/action.d/cloudflare.conf) action to block it using their WAF and API.

Answer (score 0):

You will need at least 3 failed logins from thesame IP in order for fail2ban to ban the IP.

Comment: I've tried 10+ IP addresses in a row, and it still doesn't block it. It seems that something else is jacked up. I've completely removed fail2ban from the equation and simply tried a `iptables -I INPUT -s <ip> -j DROP` and that doesn't even work.

Comment: Ensure your iptalbes service is running if not try with 'service iptables restart'

Comment: I tried that too, but I'm running Ubuntu and I get `Unit iptables.service could not be found.`

Comment: Try it with                "sudo ufw disable" "sudo ufw enable"

Comment: Just tried this, and I can see the rule still in place, but it's still not blocking. I tried a `ufw reset` just in case something was jacked up there, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that iptables and Cloudflare (and other proxy servers for that matter) just won't work. iptables only sees the connecting IP and not the X-Forwarded-For IP